# Multitude of struct errors

Tags: c, struct

It's an extremely simple and useless piece of practice code I'm working with in what is starting to seem like and extremely useless book. I was doing a struct exercise, and upon code compilation I received a handful of errors. 
Here's the offending code:

```
struct fish = {
    const char *name;
    const char *species;
    int teeth;
    int age;
};


void catalog(struct fish f)
{
    printf("%s is a %s with %i teeth. He is %i.\n", f.name, f.species, f.teeth, f.age);
}


int main()
{
struct fish snappy = {"Snappy", "piranha", 69, 4};

catalog(snappy);
return 0;
}
```

This is the **exact** code from the book, minus the struct definition above catalog. I ended up just copy pasting because I started to suspect this book was just dead wrong. The book claimed that the above code should compile and run without the struct even being defined. I've tried putting the struct definition into a header file, and I've tried removing it or adding it to different parts of the code. I get the same exact errors:

```
snappy.c:8:13: error: expected identifier or ‘(’ before ‘=’ token
struct fish = {
         ^
snappy.c:16:26: error: parameter 1 (‘f’) has incomplete type
 void catalog(struct fish f)
                      ^
snappy.c: In function ‘main’:
snappy.c:24:12: error: variable ‘snappy’ has initializer but incomplete type
 struct fish snappy = {"Snappy", "piranha", 69, 4};
        ^
snappy.c:24:12: warning: excess elements in struct initializer
snappy.c:24:12: warning: (near initialization for ‘snappy’)
snappy.c:24:12: warning: excess elements in struct initializer
snappy.c:24:12: warning: (near initialization for ‘snappy’)
snappy.c:24:12: warning: excess elements in struct initializer
snappy.c:24:12: warning: (near initialization for ‘snappy’)
snappy.c:24:12: warning: excess elements in struct initializer
snappy.c:24:12: warning: (near initialization for ‘snappy’)
snappy.c:24:17: error: storage size of ‘snappy’ isn’t known
 struct fish snappy = {"Snappy", "piranha", 69, 4};
```

Comment: beyond the typo, it is unusual to pass structures by value in C.  What is the title of this book and who wrote it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`struct fish = {` is wrong in `struct` declaration. It should be `struct fish {`. Remove `=` sign.